# How to modify Blender data from vector/arrays in Python?

Tags: python, scripting, properties

I was writing a script and discover weird thing. I have code like this:

```
import bpy
obj = bpy.context.active_object
for s in obj.scale:
    s *= 2.0
    print(s)
```

and it doesn't change scale of the object although `print(s)` shows me correct values. I thought I get a pointer to the object's property as I get pointer to the object in case with:

```
for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    # do something
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is that its not always clear when values are *wrapped* or not, that is to say, when modifying a value will apply changes back to the Blender data the values originally came from.

The rule of thumb here is that array/vector/matrix/quaternion/euler/color types wrap blender internal data, but when you get a single number from any of these types, changes to it **won't** be applied back to the original data.

Taking `Object.scale` as an example...

---

This **will** modifiy the objects scale:

```
obj.scale[0] = obj.scale[0] * 2.0

# or...
obj.scale[0] *= 2.0

# or...
scale = obj.scale
scale[0] *= 2.0
```

---

This **won't** modify the objects scale:

```
# s is a float and holds no reference to the original data
s = obj.scale[0]
s *= 2.0

# or...
# this does nothing other then to do a multiplication and ignore the result
obj.scale[0] * 2.0

# or...
# by making a copy of the scale, the reference to blender data is dropped,
# this is often useful when you *want* to get some data and manipulate it
# without touching your data in Blender.
scale = obj.scale.copy()
scale[0] *= 2.0

# or...
# by decomposing the scale value by axis,
# we get a list of floats which won't wrap original data,
# this is like '.copy()' but gives us a list rather then a Vector.
scale = [obj.scale[0], obj.scale[1], obj.scale[2]]
scale[0] *= 2.0

# or...
# this also has the effect of returning a new, modified copy.
scale = [s * 2.0 for s in obj.scale]
```

---

### Note:

While this is a `Vector`, the same thing applies to color, eulers... etc as mentioned before.

In the example given in the question, its looping over numbers, so you would have to do something like this...

```
for i, s in enumerate(obj.scale):
    obj.scale[i] = s * 2.0
```

Note that in this case Vectors can be multiplied by numbers so its best to do:

```
obj.scale *= 2.0
```

---

### Note:

if you have a `mathutils` class - Vector/Matrix/Color/Quaternion/Euler, you can check to see if they reference some other data with the readonly [is_wrapped](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_current/mathutils.html#mathutils.Vector.is_wrapped) attribute. You can even get the data they came from using [owner](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_current/mathutils.html#mathutils.Vector.owner)

Answer (score 1):

### summary

namebinding - does not affect b

```
b=a
a=42
```

modifying attributes or items - does affect b

```
b=a
a.attr=42
a[item]=360
>>>b.attr
#42
>>>b[item]
#360
```

### some more details

What happens when you call (see [for loop](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement))

```
for elem in obj:
```

is, that an iterator will be retrieved from the obj like this

```
obj_iter=iter(obj)
```

This iterator has a method `__next__` which can be called by

```
next(obj_iter)
```

and will return the next element in the collection. The for-loop repeately calls `__next__`, assigns the returned value to the variable `elem`

```
elem=next(obj_iter)
```

and executes the body on each turn until the iterator raises the `StopIteration` exception signalizing that there are'nt any elements left.

If the elements in `obj` are mutable you can modify the elements .*attributes* or [*items*] with the value given to `elem`.

In your example you are rebinding a new value to the iteration variable 's name. (see [assignment](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements))